# Check if conditionally hidden textboxes have values

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, panel

I have a list of YES/NO questions and each question has a radio button indicating the answer. When the user selects YES, a `panel` will be visible and it has textboxes inside it for the additional required input. When the user answers YES, they MUST fill in the textboxes that appear.

Currently I'm hard-coding it this way:

```
            if (txtQ1Specify.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ1Specify.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ2Specify.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ2Specify.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ3Specify.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ3Specify.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ4SpecifyCompany.Visible == true || txtQ4SpecifyRelative.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ4SpecifyCompany.Text.Length == 0 || txtQ4SpecifyRelative.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ5SpecifyCompany.Visible == true || txtQ5SpecifyRelative.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ5SpecifyCompany.Text.Length == 0 || txtQ5SpecifyRelative.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ6Specify.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ6Specify.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
            if (txtQ7Specify.Visible == true)
            {
                if (txtQ7Specify.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
                }
            }
```

After this checking I want to execute some code.

The page looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I check for textbox inputs based in visibility?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to find out if there are any visible and empty TextBoxes like so:

```
var query =
    from t in Page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    where t.Visible && t.Text == ""
    select t;

bool hasUnanswered = query.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done on the client side .

1. First you need to identify which all text box are visible . For this you can use jquery [Visible Selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
2. Now If more than one text box is visible . Show some message to the user and focus and highlight the text box which need to be filled .

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     var visibleCount =$('input[type="text"]:visible').length;
>   if (visibleCount  > 0)
>   {
>      // Add your logic here
>    }
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this client-side validation. But I was looking for server-side, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using a very long `if` statement. Here goes nothing:

```
if ((pnlQ1Yes.Visible == true && txtQ1Specify.Text.Length == 0) ||
            (pnlQ2Yes.Visible == true && txtQ2Specify.Text.Length == 0) ||
            (pnlQ3Yes.Visible == true && txtQ3Specify.Text.Length == 0) ||
            (pnlQ4Yes.Visible == true && (txtQ4SpecifyCompany.Text.Length == 0 || txtQ4SpecifyRelative.Text.Length == 0)) ||
            (pnlQ5Yes.Visible == true && (txtQ5SpecifyCompany.Text.Length == 0 || txtQ5SpecifyRelative.Text.Length == 0)) ||
            (pnlQ6Yes.Visible == true && txtQ6Specify.Text.Length == 0) ||
            (pnlQ7Yes.Visible == true && txtQ7Specify.Text.Length == 0))
{
    lblError.Text = "Please answer all questions.";
}
else   
{
    ...
}
```

It first checks if the panel is `visible`, then it checks the textbox inside the panel for values. Then I repeat this kind of checking for the rest of the panels and textboxes.